# Rails: Is it not possible/necessary to html_escape all email text (in the view)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, quotation-marks, html-escape-characters

can anyone tell me if it is normal and OK for Rails to turn a normal quotation mark (") into & q u o t ; (and not keep the normal quotation mark) when it is html_escape-d in an email view?

I.e.:

h(whatever_text_that_contains_normal_quotation_marks) in an email view "signup_mail.erb".

Because that would mean that email content could not be completely escaped, right?

Thanks for any hints!

Tom

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by "that email content could not be completely escaped"?

Comment: I mean that any quotation marks could not be "html_escaped" (at least, in my code it doesn't work). But then I ask myself, is it actually necessary (security-wise) to html_escape text that will appear in emails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, since Rails 3 does h() all by itself, the question is no longer valid.